# How to stop org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate caching the response?

Tags: spring, caching, resttemplate

In my Spring-boot project for REST HTTP calls I am using org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.

The problem is that it is caching the response, meaning that when I call it for the first time I get back the right response, but when I update data on server related to current API and when I call same API for the second time it still returns me the old response, so it is probably taking the `ResponseEntity<T>` from cache? I am not sure.. How to get the latest version of the response each time I call same API?

Here is how I make HTTP call

```
public <T> ResponseEntity<T> doQueryApi(String url, HttpMethod httpMethod, Object anyObject, HttpHeaders requestHeaders, Class<T> responseType) throws RestClientException {

        HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity(anyObject, requestHeaders);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        ResponseEntity<T> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, httpMethod, requestEntity, responseType);
        return responseEntity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the RestTemplate is caching and not the server itself? AFAIK if you don't configure caching, RestTemplate doesn't do it by itself.

Answer (score 4):

You can try force no-caching requests in request headers this way:

```
// Force the request expires
requestHeaders.setExpires(0);
// Cache-Control: private, no-store, max-age=0
requestHeaders.setCacheControl("private, no-store, max-age=0");
```

I had similiar problem and it worked fine.